# Group or combine a long query when checking multiple values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query where I only want to show results where the data was recently updated (yesterday or sooner).

My query pulls data from 4 different tables, so I need to check the `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` column of each table.

If any of them have a `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` value that was yesterday or sooner, then I want to pull all that data.

So I added this to my query:

```
AND (a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
 OR b.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
 OR c.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
 OR d.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0))
```

I think it's working, but is there a way to shorten the statement because it is very long and confusing.

Comment: One of your right parentheses appears to be in the wrong place (made obvious by the formatting I've added).

Comment: @ThomA thanks!  I fixed it but it still seems give me the same results?

Comment: Not really, in truth. You could use an `EXISTS` with an unpivot (read `VALUES` table construct), but I'm: 1. Not sure that would be less characters 2. Not sure how it would affect performance in your environment.

Comment: Can you include enough sample data so that we can play with the actual query? There might be a solution, but it's hard to guess from what you've given us.

Comment: FWIW (and I know you said you're using 2012) if you had SQL 2022, you could probably use the `GREATEST` function.

Comment: That's kind of par for the course with SQL. It feels a bit verbose but it's not really confusing.

Comment: Nice point on `GREATEST` @Xedni, though in the `WHERE` that probably would have SARGability problems. Certainly, if the OP was on 2022, it would be worth a test though.

Comment: you can also add a cross apply and move the `dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)`inside that to avoid repeating same thing over and over

Answer (score 4):

This could possibly be a use case for [ANY/SOME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/some-any-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The `ANY` function returns true if any value in the subquery meets the predicate you apply to it. So in this case, you could use the predicate `where getdate() - 1 > any (...dates)`

Since there is no sample data to work with here, I'm completely guessing at what your query looks like, but this should give you an idea of how you could structure your predicate.

```
declare @DaysBack int = 5
;with a as
(
    select dt = getdate() - 10 union all
    select getdate() - 9
), b as
(
    select dt = getdate() - 8 union all
    select getdate() - 7
), c as
(
    select dt = getdate() - 6 union all
    select getdate() - 5
)
select *
from a
where getdate() - @DaysBack > any 
(
    select dt from a union all
    select dt from b union all
    select dt from c
)
```

Or with your columns:

```
....
where DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0)) > any 
(
    select LAST_UPDATE_DATE from a union all
    select LAST_UPDATE_DATE from b union all
    select LAST_UPDATE_DATE from c
)
```

As a side note, I was dealing with a SO question yesterday which discussed ANY/SOME which is why it's fresh in my mind but I don't usually use these functions. However it does seem it might be a valid alternate syntax. If you want to know more on these functions, I'd recommend reading [All, Any, and Some: The Three Stooges](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2009/08/all-any-and-some-three-stooges.html)

Comment: Anyone (slight pun intended) who can make use of ANY in tsql gets my vote

Comment: One suggestion, use `UNION ALL`; this'll avoid the implicit `DISTINCT` operation, which could be quite costly.

Comment: Good call; thanks. Fixing that

Comment: You only fixed the first set of unions :)

Comment: /facepalm There we go.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative I can think of would be something like an `EXISTS` where you unpivot the data. Though, as I mention in the comments this probably isn't less characters. As for performance, I don't have a good scenario in my environment to test this on, and someone else might look at this and find it *more* confusing.

Any way, if you wanted to use an `EXISTS` instead, it would look something like this:

```sql
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM (VALUES(a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE),
                        (b.LAST_UPDATE_DATE),
                        (c.LAST_UPDATE_DATE),
                        (d.LAST_UPDATE_DATE))V(LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
            WHERE V.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),0))
```

If your concern is the expression, `DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),0)`, then I agree that's a little confusing. I think `DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))` would be more obvious to others what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid repeating the date expression:

```
from ... cross apply
    (values (dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0))) as v(start_of_yesterday)
where ... and (
        a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= start_of_yesterday
    or  b.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= start_of_yesterday
    or  c.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= start_of_yesterday
    or  d.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= start_of_yesterday
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information you provided in your question:

```
DECLARE @TargetDate AS DATETIME = dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)

/* The rest of your query here */
AND (
    a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= @TargetDate
    OR b.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= @TargetDate 
    OR c.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= @TargetDate
    OR d.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= @TargetDate
)
```